# Correct use of generics in Java

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to set my custom event management system - just for learning.

I have created a structure of:

- an `Event` - which is the simplest component that will carry any information
- a `Listener` - which will accept one or more `Event`s
- an `EventManager` which will be responsible to submit any Events to its registered Listeners

I have used generics in order to make use of Java's strong types but I've hit a dead-end as I can't get past by a compiler "Unchecked" warning

The classes are as below:

Event:

```java
// no functionality, just a placeholder for events
interface Event { }
```

Listener:

```java
interface EventListener<T extends Event> {
    boolean accept(Event event);

    void submit(T event);
}
```

EventManager:

```java
public class EventManager {

    private final List<EventListener<? extends Event>> listeners;

    public EventManager(List<EventListener<? extends Event>> listeners) {
        this.listeners = listeners;
    }

    public void sendEvent(Event event) {
        this.listeners.stream()
                .filter(l -> l.accept(event))
                .forEach(l -> l.submit(getEvent(event)));
    }

    private <T extends Event> T getEvent(Event event) {
        return (T) event;  // <-- warning
    }
}
```

I'm expecting a client to call:

```java
ConcreteEvent event = new ConcreteEvent(); // <-- That implements Event
eventManager.sendEvent(event);
```

The warning is in the last method, `getEvent`, which makes sense.

My question is:

- Is there any alternative design that wouldn't raise a compilation warning and make correct use of java generics? I'd like to submit any event through the `EventManager` and that event would be processed by one or many listeners

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the `getEvent` method? It's just passing back the same object passed to it and casting it to an arbitrary subtype which may not match.

Comment: @Tenfour04 what they are trying to accomplish is that the code compiles. Without that, it wouldn't - the warning is indicating that, whilst the code now compilers, the compiler is not making any guarantee that it is 'correct' (devoid of cast-less ClassCastException issues).

Comment: @rzwitserloot It's hard to suggest an alternate solution when we don't know what problem we're solving. I can say, "just remove the generics and return Event" which would make it safe, but then it's a pointless method. I don't know what the method is going to be used for.

Comment: @Tenfour04 The provided code as well as the title ("an event listener system") is definitely more than enough to know what OP wants. No more detail is required for this question.

Comment: @Tenfour04 As @rzwitserloot already pointed out the question is how I can workaround the compilation warning by providing an alternative approach/design. And to address your question, if you don't use the `getEvent` method then the code doesn't compile, since the `submit` method expects anything that extends `Event` but we can't provide it - hence the explicit casting I've added.

Comment: What I missed was that you were calling `getEvent()` from within the EventListener. I misread it as marked `public` so I assumed it was for external use which didn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generics link things at compile (i.e. 'as you write the code') time. For example, in:

```
private <T extends Event> T getEvent(Event event) {
  return (T) event;  // <-- warning
}
```

This isn't accomplishing anything meaningful, you're just dressing up a cast: You have declared a `T` for this method, but whenever you declare a typevar, you must use it in at least 2 places or it is either a pointless exercise or (as is the case here), a hack. You *are* using it in 2 places here, but the second place is in a cast to T which does absolutely nothing: That is an assertion: "Compiler, shut up, I know what I am doing, trust me, it will be a T". Neither at write time, **nor at runtime**, does that `(T)`  do anything. No check is performed, and this line cannot possibly throw a ClassCastException. Instead, the code of the event handler does an invisible cast and that one would fail: You'd get a CCE on a line with zero casts on it, which is confusing. That is what the warning is trying to tell you: The compiler cannot actually guarantee type safety here.

Your problem is that this 'link things at compile time' job is **impossible** here: You have a list of eventlisteners of who-knows-what (literally: `? extends Event` - ? = who knows), and there is thus no linking 2 usages in your code. There is no way to add such a compile-time linkage.

### Okay, so what do I do?

*IF* you are on board with limiting the kinds of events an event handler can handle to solely typevar-less types (so no `NewDataUploadedEvent<X>` - only concrete types that themselves has no generics), there is a solution: Reify the type by explicitly passing it along.

Before I dive into the code, a note:

Your `accept` method accepts any event, but your submit method only accepts a T. This is bad design and you should fix it. What does it mean if a non-T Event type is nevertheless accepted by your boolean-returning method? The only way you could possibly pass it to the `submit` method is by breaking type safety, which makes no sense. More generally, why do you have an accept method? You're just forcing somebody writing an event handler to duplicate code and create bizarre questions ("What do I do if an event is passing to my submit method that I cannot handle?"). Why not just have a `submit` method which can throw an exception to indicate it doesn't want it, or returning a boolean to indicate this? I'll address this in the coming examples; I don't like writing bad code style in answers; makes me feel like I'm teaching bad habits.

On that note, the `forEach` terminal on a stream op, especially if no actual stream ops are done (no mapping or filtering or whatnot) is usually a code smell: You lose control flow, checked exception, and local variable transparency, and you gain absolutely nothing in return. Just write a `for(:)` loop. I know, I know. You have a new hammer, it is very shiny, and it is making you think everything is a nail. But, it's not a nail. You *CAN* butter toast with a hammer, but, the butterknife is the better tool for it. So it goes here. I'll fix that too.

1. Add a `Class<T>` returning method to the interface:

```
interface EventListener<T extends Event> {
    Class<T> getType();
    void submit(T event) throws EventNotAcceptedException;
}
```

Now you can write your event loop like so:

```
public void sendEvent(Event event) {
  for (EventListener<?> listener : listeners) tryListener(listener, event);
}

private <T extends Event> boolean tryListener(EventListener<T> listener, T event) {
  Class<T> type = listener.getType();
  T obj;
  try {
    obj = type.cast(event);
  } catch (ClassCastException e) {
    return false;
  }

  try {
    listener.submit(obj);
    return true;
  } catch (EventNotAcceptedException e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

2. Go on a reflection spree

It is technically possible to use reflection to fetch the `<X>` in a `class Foo extends Bar<X>`. However, you get the *literal* X, straight from the source file, and not what it actually is. That's great if you write:

```
class UploadHandler extends EventHandler<UploadEvent> {}
```

as it means you can get `UploadEvent.class` out of that. It's not so good if you have:

```
class GeneralizedHandler<T> extends EventHandle<T> {
   private final Consumer<T> consumer;
   // boilerplate here
}
```

as you'll just be getting `T` which isn't what you need and you can't use that to do type checks and casts. You'd have to *runtime* error out if someone tries to pull this stunt on you, you can't catch this at compile time. If you're willing, well, doable, but complicated. the `j.l.Class` API has the `getGenericSuperclass()` method, which returns a `Type`, which is useless (it has no methods), but you'd check if gGS returns a `java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType`, and if it does, call its `getActualTypeArguments()` method, whose first arg should, presumably, be a `java.lang.Class`, and that's the one. You can then cast and the like from there with guarantees that it's 'the right type', so to speak. However, there is no way to write that without getting the compiler warning. You solve that by isolating the code in a single method as you did in your `getEvent` method in your question, and sticking a `@SuppressWarnings` on that.

You can extract the proper type as an event listener is registered, storing your event listeners not as a `List<EventListener>` but, to make a container class: `private static class EventContainer<T> { EventListener<T> listener; Class<T> eventType; }` - this lets you throw an exception if someone passes an eventlistener impl that isn't defined to `extends EventListener<SomethingConcrete>`, as soon as possible (it's always good to throw sooner rather than later), and you can now use that `eventType` to call `cast` and friends - and there won't be any warnings.

Comment: First of all thanks for writing such detailed answer, really appreciate it. I will opt for the first suggestion as it's clearer - but thanks for providing the reflection, I will play with it. To address some of your questions: 1) I'm using the `accept` method because I'd like an event listener to be able to accept as many subclasses of its type as possible. For instance, if a `UserListener` accepts any `UserEvent` then I wanted to be able to define a listener that accepts `UserEvent` && `LoggedUserEvent` but not `LockedUserEvent` -- all are subtypes of `UserEvent`.

Comment: Your solution is moving the "can I handle this event" logic from the Listener to the EventManager. Meaning that the logic is now changed from "let me see if I can handle this event" to "I can only accept this event". Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Final note, I see that you mention that the `forEach` usage is redundant. Are there any resources about why - for that simple case - is not advised to use the stream op? Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @Skod if you are keeping the `accept` method, it should also be getting a `T` and not an `Event`, to avoid the scenario where your accept method decides to accept a non-T Event. In your example, T is UserEvent, so all works out still.

Comment: @Skod remember subtyping relationships: If you have: `class UserEventListener<UserEvent> { ... }`, __it cannot possibly accept non-UserEvents__ - the `submit` method cannot be invoked. It _can_ accept any UserEvent and any LoggedUserEvent, etc. Why not do the filtering of 'this is not even a UserEvent' in the framework and avoid the DRY violation?

Comment: forEach is not redundant; you need to loop through a list and there are 2 ways to do it: `for(:)` and `.forEach`. In such a simple case, `forEach` is strictly inferior. As I said, they are not transparent for checked exceptions, (mutable) local vars, and control flow - a web search for those terms will find a ton of information.

Comment: And to be clear, the only part of 'do you accept this kind of event?' code that moved to the framework is to check if the incoming event isn't `instanceof T` so to speak. The concept of the handler itself rejecting a message remains - whether you use "`submit` throws an `EventNotAcceptedEx`" model or a "there is a separate `accept` method" model.

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense! Thanks for the extra details!